# Exercise 1-13: Why does this code not work in Code Blocks?

Tags: c

Why does this code not work in code blocks...I can enter in text but I'm not able to print the desired histogram? The purpose of the code is to print a histogram. It's exercise 1-13 in the C Programming Language

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXHIST 15
#define MAXWORD 11
#define IN      1
#define OUT     0

main()
{
    int c, i, nc, state;
    int len;
    int maxvalue;
    int ovflow;
    int wl[MAXWORD];

    state = OUT;
    nc = 0;
    ovflow = 0;
    for(i=0; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
        wl[i] = 0;
    while(( c = getchar()) !=EOF) {
        if (c==' '|| c=='\n'|| c == '\t' ){
            state = OUT;
            if (nc>0)
                if (nc < MAXWORD)
                    ++wl[nc];
                else
                    ++ovflow;

            nc=0;
        }else if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            nc = 1;
        }else
            ++nc;
    }
    maxvalue = 0;
    for (i = 1; 1<MAXWORD; ++i)
        if (wl[i] > maxvalue)
            maxvalue = wl[i];

    for (i=1; i<MAXWORD; ++i){
        printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);
        if (wl[i]> 0){
            if ((len=wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <=0)
                len = 1;
        }else
            len = 0;
        while (len > 0 ) {
            putchar('*');
            --len;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    if (ovflow > 0)
            printf("There are %d words >= %d\n", ovflow, MAXWORD);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to trace the execution of your code. Or even basic debug statements. That's the right way to debug a program instead of asking others to do debugging for you. Then you should be able to find out for yourself that `1<MAXWORD` should be `i<MAXWORD`

Comment: yes... gdb is your friend, or whatever debugger comes with code blocks

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

This line is a big problem:

```
for (i = 1; 1<MAXWORD; ++i)
```

You have a typo where you compare `1` to `MAXWORD`.  The line should probably be this:

```
for (i = 1; i<MAXWORD; ++i)
```

Also not sure why you are incrementing `i` before you enter the loop instead of after.